# Use generic implementation of wxDataViewCtrl on OSX

Tags: wxwidgets

By default `wxDataViewCtrl` has native implementation under OSX. How can I use generic implementation of `wxDataViewCtrl` under OSX.
I do not want to make any changes in wxWidgets Code. I would prefer a macro or some specific header.

Also I am thinking how I can use native and generic implementations both at the same time.

Tried the way suggested:

Following errors while building wxWidgets dynamic library:

```
./src/osx/dataview_osx.cpp:101:38: error: no member named 'GetDataViewPeer' in 'wxDataViewCtrl'
  noFailureFlag = m_DataViewCtrlPtr->GetDataViewPeer()->Add(parent,item);
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
./src/osx/dataview_osx.cpp:112:38: error: no member named 'GetDataViewPeer' in 'wxDataViewCtrl'
  noFailureFlag = m_DataViewCtrlPtr->GetDataViewPeer()->Add(parent,items);
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
./src/osx/dataview_osx.cpp:123:26: error: no member named 'GetDataViewPeer' in 'wxDataViewCtrl'
  if (m_DataViewCtrlPtr->GetDataViewPeer()->Update(GetOwner()->GetParent(item),item))
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
./src/osx/dataview_osx.cpp:153:28: error: no member named 'GetDataViewPeer' in 'wxDataViewCtrl'
    if (m_DataViewCtrlPtr->GetDataViewPeer()->Update(GetOwner()->GetParent(items[indexItem]),items[indexItem]))
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
./src/osx/dataview_osx.cpp:178:22: error: no member named 'SetDeleting' in 'wxDataViewCtrl'
  m_DataViewCtrlPtr->SetDeleting(true);
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
./src/osx/dataview_osx.cpp:179:38: error: no member named 'GetDataViewPeer' in 'wxDataViewCtrl'
  noFailureFlag = m_DataViewCtrlPtr->GetDataViewPeer()->Remove(parent,item);
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
./src/osx/dataview_osx.cpp:181:22: error: no member named 'SetDeleting' in 'wxDataViewCtrl'
  m_DataViewCtrlPtr->SetDeleting(false);
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
./src/osx/dataview_osx.cpp:197:22: error: no member named 'SetDeleting' in 'wxDataViewCtrl'
  m_DataViewCtrlPtr->SetDeleting(true);
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
./src/osx/dataview_osx.cpp:199:38: error: no member named 'GetDataViewPeer' in 'wxDataViewCtrl'
  noFailureFlag = m_DataViewCtrlPtr->GetDataViewPeer()->Remove(parent,items);
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
./src/osx/dataview_osx.cpp:201:22: error: no member named 'SetDeleting' in 'wxDataViewCtrl'
  m_DataViewCtrlPtr->SetDeleting(false);
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
./src/osx/dataview_osx.cpp:212:26: error: no member named 'GetDataViewPeer' in 'wxDataViewCtrl'
  if (m_DataViewCtrlPtr->GetDataViewPeer()->Update(GetOwner()->GetParent(item),item))
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
./src/osx/dataview_osx.cpp:233:29: error: no member named 'GetDataViewPeer' in 'wxDataViewCtrl'
  return m_DataViewCtrlPtr->GetDataViewPeer()->Reload();
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
./src/osx/dataview_osx.cpp:238:22: error: no member named 'GetDataViewPeer' in 'wxDataViewCtrl'
  m_DataViewCtrlPtr->GetDataViewPeer()->Resort();
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
./src/osx/dataview_osx.cpp:252:55: error: no member named 'GetColumnPtr' in 'wxDataViewCtrl'; did you mean 'GetColumnAt'?
          wxDataViewColumn* column(m_DataViewCtrlPtr->GetColumnPtr(col));
                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                      GetColumnAt
./include/wx/generic/dataview.h:248:23: note: 'GetColumnAt' declared here
    wxDataViewColumn *GetColumnAt(unsigned int pos) const;
                      ^
./src/osx/dataview_osx.cpp:267:28: error: no member named 'GetDataViewPeer' in 'wxDataViewCtrl'
        m_DataViewCtrlPtr->GetDataViewPeer()->SetRowHeight(item,height);
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
./src/osx/dataview_osx.cpp:287:57: error: no member named 'GetColumnPtr' in 'wxDataViewCtrl'; did you mean 'GetColumnAt'?
            wxDataViewColumn* column(m_DataViewCtrlPtr->GetColumnPtr(col));
                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                        GetColumnAt
./include/wx/generic/dataview.h:248:23: note: 'GetColumnAt' declared here
    wxDataViewColumn *GetColumnAt(unsigned int pos) const;
                      ^
./src/osx/dataview_osx.cpp:302:30: error: no member named 'GetDataViewPeer' in 'wxDataViewCtrl'
          m_DataViewCtrlPtr->GetDataViewPeer()->SetRowHeight(items[itemIndex],height);
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ^
./src/osx/dataview_osx.cpp:312:53: error: no member named 'GetColumnPtr' in 'wxDataViewCtrl'; did you mean 'GetColumnAt'?
      wxDataViewColumn *column = m_DataViewCtrlPtr->GetColumnPtr(col);
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~
                                                    GetColumnAt
./include/wx/generic/dataview.h:248:23: note: 'GetColumnAt' declared here
    wxDataViewColumn *GetColumnAt(unsigned int pos) const;
                      ^
./src/osx/dataview_osx.cpp:314:20: error: no member named 'GetWidthVariable' in 'wxDataViewColumn'
      if ( column->GetWidthVariable() == wxCOL_WIDTH_AUTOSIZE )
           ~~~~~~  ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make: *** [advdll_dataview_osx.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

`#include <wx/generic/dataview.h>` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to globally predefine `wxHAS_GENERIC_DATAVIEWCTRL` and rebuild both wxWidgets and your application using it.

There is currently no way to use both the native and generic implementations of this control in the same build.

Comment: tried with wxHAS_GENERIC_DATAVIEWCTRL and rebuilt wxWidgets, got many linking errors

Comment: You also need to add `src/generic/datavgen.cpp` to your own project.

Comment: I am getting the errors while building wx dynamic library itself. Please check the errors in asked question

Answer (score 0):

We need to build wxWidgets with both:

```
wxHAS_GENERIC_DATAVIEWCTRL
wxUSE_GENERICDATAVIEWCTRL
```

Only `wxHAS_GENERIC_DATAVIEWCTRL` will not work. Note, now I am able to use the generic implementation of wxWidgets on OSX.